# Is the countable product of normed spaces a normed space with this "norm"

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider the product $\mathcal{N} = \mathcal{N}_{1} \times \mathcal{N}_{2} \times \mathcal{N}_{3} \times \dots$ where $\mathcal{N}_{1}, \mathcal{N}_{2}, \mathcal{N}_{3}, \dots$ are normed spaces with norms $\| \cdot \|_{1}, \| \cdot \|_{2}, \| \cdot \|_{3}, \dots,$ respectively. I would like to know if the function $$ \| \vec{u} \| =  \left( \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \| u_{n} \|_{n} ^{p} \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}, \text{ defined for } \vec{u} = \left( u_{1}, u_{2}, u_{3}, \dots \right) \in \mathcal{N}$$ is a norm on $\mathcal{N}.$

The function defined above satisfies the two first conditions to be a norm. However I am having a hard time figuring out if it satisfies the Triangle Inequality since the only method I know uses the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, but this requires a product between vectors and I don't have this concept in $\mathcal{N}.$ So I would like to ask here if somebody knows how to prove it does, or has a counterexample showing it doesn't.

Comment: You may want to restrict te definiton to $V=\{(u_1,u_2,\ldots)\in\mathcal{N}\ s.t.\ (\|u_1\|_1,\|u_2\|_2,\ldots)\in\ell^p\}$. Here it is indeed a norm, and the proof is analogous to that of [Minkowski inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality)